# How to add new project to ARC Advanced Rest Client standalone version

Tags: advanced-rest-client

I'm having problem finding a way to add new project.

Tried to google but im unable to find option anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you save a request, you give the request a name, an optional description and then an optional project name. just type a new name or select an existing project name, then hit save.